# No pg_conftool on Centos 7?

Tags: centos7, postgresql, yum

I'm adapting scripts that configure PostgreSQL 9.6 and 10.x on Ubuntu 16.04 to also work on Centos 7.4. I'm missing the *pg_conftool* utility which allows me to identify and modify aspects of the PostgreSQL configuration in a clean, high-level fasion, and I get no results from *yum whatprovides pg_conftool*. What Yum package would I need to install to have it available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pg_conftool isn't packaged by CentOS or EPEL. You could always check out the [source](https://github.com/petere/postgresql-common) yourself and use the included .spec file to build your own RPM.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mention of `pg_conftool` in the PostgreSQL documentation and I cannot find it in any of the CentOS packages. Given this, I expect this is a Debian/Ubuntu specific tool.

You will find [server tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/reference-server.html) and [client tools](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/reference-client.html) listed in the official documentation.

Of these, the tool [pg_controldata](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgcontroldata.html) seems the closest match to your use-case but the documentation only talks about retrieving cluster-wide configuration rather than setting it.

For setting data, you could modify the config files whilst using [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pg-ctl.html) to stop, start, or reload the servers as required.

#### Packages

`pg_controldata` is definitely available in [Ubuntu 16](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/postgresql-9.5) and [Ubuntu 17](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/postgresql-9.6) (see the *list of files* link next to your system architecture)

For CentOS, I don't have anything to hand that will give me file listings for the packages. If you aren't already, then I suggest that you use the [official PostgreSQL repos](https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php) rather than the default system repos.

Comment: Couldn't find *pg_controldata* on neither Ubuntu 16.04 nor CentOS 7, unfortunately.

Comment: @YitzikC *pg_controldata* is definitely in Ubuntu (see revised answer). I don't have anything to hand to check the CentOS packages.

Comment: Thanks @Marvin, now I can find it. It's not really a substitute for pg_conftool, though.